# Unicode or tab definition for the three colored dots representing Julia

Tags: unicode, julia, mastodon

On different mastodon instances Julia users added the three colored dots to their username. In the page source it appears as `:julia:`, but I cannot display this emoji as `\julia`. How to generate it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Przemyslaw has it right, but while there's no official Unicode character for Julia (and I wouldn't hold my breath on this one...), Unicode has a "private use area" which allows fonts to define their own characters.

The JuliaMono font makes use of this to provide a character for the Julia dots, as well as other Julia related things.

https://juliamono.netlify.app/

Answer (score 2):

Julia REPL uses Unicode characters that you can enter using `\` followed by style similar to LaTeX. However, there is (not yet) a special unicode character that represents Julia logo. When people write on forums `:julia:` this gets replaced by an icon (not a character) but in Julia REPL only Unicode characters are available.

Having said that, there is a page devoted to the logo of Julia language you might want to have a look at:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia-logo-graphics